# CSS animation bug [Safari OSX] - transition animation still there after click "back"

Tags: javascript, css, debugging, animation, safari

I've run into a strange bug. On my website I have an animation, when you click a case-link it will cover the screen with color and then open the case. Then you enter the case.

If you are using Safari OSX and then click back (The browsers back button), the colored rectangle will still be showing on the front page even though it should go back to it's original place.

See the bug yourself by click a case on the website in Safari OSX: http://davidbograd.com/

Do you have an idea how to fix this?

Comment: I can reproduce this behavior: In my case an CSS animation started before leaving the page is seen ending when clicking the "back" button.